# The error message text is so lost and faded

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, error-message

The text of the error message used to be white...
But it hasn't been washed for a while, and only the dismiss button is still clean white.

> [image]

Comment: Your soul-crushing title [narrowly escaped destruction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50857).

Comment: It's fashionable to make text completely unreadable on web pages. See e.g. [this](https://backchannel.com/how-the-web-became-unreadable-a781ddc711b6) and [this](http://contrastrebellion.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been washed thoroughly with unicorn powers and maple syrup. Take this vote lock error message for example:

[image]

It is now white and not the weird grey in your screenshot/snippet.

Comment: I agree. I tested it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLZjB.png